# How to search inside a table with textWatcher or different

Tags: java, android, list, search

So I have a table of data I download into the app from a online server, I have a search button that at click brings up a AlertDialog where I want the user to enter the searching text and it looks like this:

```
public void buscar() {
    final EditText myView = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    myView.setHint("Introduce texto aqui");
    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setView(myView);
    alt_bld.setMessage("Introduce el texto o nombre del medio que deseas buscar:")

            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Listo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
        {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count)   
        {  
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {  
        }
    };
    buscartext = myView.getText();
    myView.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    alert.setTitle("Buscar");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.searcha);
    alert.show();
}
```

It works by the means of showing the alert dialog and asking for the search text, but obviously I don't now exactly how it works, I have try this inside the onTextChanged and the afterTextChanged:

```
for(webResult currentItem: arrayOfWebData)
    {
        //Check if the Medio property of the current item matches the search
        if(currentItem.Medio.equals(s))
        { 
            FilteredArrayOfWebItems.add(currentItem);
        }
     } 
            // here call my list adapter to display items
```

webResult is the table from the internet and aFilteredArrayOfWebItems is meant to be list resulting from the search, but it doesn't work. I know currentItem.Medio.equals(s) is checking only one column of my table and I need to search in more than one plus that line is not good for searching because of the .equal How can I make a in-discriminated (%searchtext%) search? and use this textWatcher or should I use another way for searching in my table?

Comment: This might work better for you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: I guess for suggesting the word that needs to be search is good, but that's not the case of my question, my question is more base on how to search inside my table